# Magento 1.9.4.1 Double Tax issue

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat, magento-1.9.3.4

I'm having a problem with VAT value. I've searched for a solution in this forum and on other sites, but none seems to be solving mine. To be precise:
I'm using Magento to list my offers on eBay.

When customers make their order, my WMS system catches this order from Magento and creates order only with proper value when client orders 1 piece of 1 SKU + shipping (also works when order shows 2 or more pieces of same SKU) in the WMS system. When someone orders 2 SKU's or more, my whole VAT is being doubled by WMS, even if Magento shows proper value. 
I tried to change setting in magento (also checked config.xml file), but after that double VAT was applied to even order with 1 SKU. I have restored settings to previous and now I'm waiting for new 2 or more SKU's order, but I'm afraid that the problem still will be the same.

I have spoken with IT service in my company but they blame settings in Magento, which seems to be fine. Does any1 have some clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after migrating from Magento 1.9.3.X to 1.9.4.X

There is a bug, and the bugfix is here, it worked for me.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/Magento-1-9-4-Tax-VAT-in-Shopping-Cart-is-Wrong-incorrect-after/td-p/114857

Regards